# I have both tables with wp_ prefix and with changed prefix in wordpress database what should i do?

Tags: database, wordpress

I tried to change the prefix with the AIOWPS plugin and it destroyed my site. It wouldn't let me in. I somehow restored the database backup and somehow managed to sign in. Now i have both tables.. with and without changed prefix. I am not a tech guy and it was very overwhelming for me. 
I wont care much about these tables as long as they don't make my site slower or cause future problems, **but i don't know that so that is another question!** 
So what should i do? Should i delete the tables with changed prefix?

Comment: If the tables with the changed prefix are exact duplicates, and there are no functions/plugins referencing them, then you should be able to drop the duplicate tables from the database without issue.  Having duplicate tables in your DB that you don't use generally won't impact performance unless you have an excessive number of duplicates and gigantic tables.

Comment: How do i know if there are no functions/plugins referencing them